# Python guitar fretboard pitch/frequency implementation

Tags: python, audio

I'm working on an application which, to make my life easier, requires a numeric converter for notes into frequencies that do a certain number of notes per second, **including chords**.

I found [this article](http://forum.cakewalk.com/Guitar-notes-and-frequencies-chart-included-m869331.aspx) which highlighted the frequencies of each note, which manually blended (with pyaudio) to make my own rendition of Smoke On The Water using the mapped sequence from the article for each note.

This would work, and I could create chords by creating parallel processes, though I have no way of converting a note or *tab number* into a specific pitch. Most of my data is in the form of:

```
0 3 5 0 3 6 5 0 3 5 3 0
```

Essentially, I require an equation or function which can return the frequency for the input, with 0 being an open E-low-string and each value increase by 1 is one-fret up the fretboard (1 = F).

**Isn't there a blatant pattern?**

I'd wish so, but I suspect sine waves are the suspect. Taking the difference of E to F is **5.1**, and F to F# is **5.2** and finally, F# to G being **5.5**.

Thanks for any help, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen [aubio](https://aubio.org/manual/latest/cli.html#aubionotes)? With `aubionotes` (has Python bindings!) you can extract notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Isn't there a blatant pattern?**

Yes, for music in general there is. Two adjacent notes are separated by a factor of 2^(1/12). [Wikipedia - Twelfth root of two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelfth_root_of_two) [Wikipedia - Semitone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitone). It tried this out on the numbers in your linked article and the pattern fit perfectly to the number of significant digits shown in the article.

**EDIT**
OP asked for some code. Here's a quick -- but verbosely documented -- shot at that:

```
# A semitone (half-step) is the twelfth root of two
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitone
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelfth_root_of_two
SEMITONE_STEP = 2 ** (1/12)

# Standard tuning for a guitar - EADGBE
LOW_E_FREQ = 82.4    # Baseline - low 'E' is 82.4Hz
# In standard tuning, we use the fifth fret to tune the next string
# except for the next-to-highest string where we use the fourth fret.
STRING_STEPS = [5, 5, 5, 4, 5]

# Number of frets can vary but we will just presume it's 24 frets
N_FRETS = 24

# This will be a list of the frequencies of all six strings,
# a list of six lists, where each list is that string's frequencies at each fret
fret_freqs = []
# Start with the low string as our reference point
# We just short-hand the math of multipliying by SEMITONE_STEP over and over
fret_freqs.append([LOW_E_FREQ * (SEMITONE_STEP ** n) for n in range(N_FRETS)])
# Now go through the upper strings and base of each lower-string's fret, just like
# when we are tuning a guitar
for tuning_fret in STRING_STEPS:
    # Pick off the nth fret of the previous string and use it as our base frequency
    base_freq = fret_freqs[-1][tuning_fret]
    fret_freqs.append([base_freq * (SEMITONE_STEP ** n) for n in range(N_FRETS)])

for stringFreqs in fret_freqs:
    # We don't need 14 decimal places of precision, thank you very much.
    print(["{:.1f}".format(f) for f in stringFreqs])
```

Output of this:

```
['82.4', '87.3', '92.5', '98.0', '103.8', '110.0', '116.5', '123.5', '130.8', '138.6', '146.8', '155.6', '164.8', '174.6', '185.0', '196.0', '207.6', '220.0', '233.1', '246.9', '261.6', '277.2', '293.6', '311.1'] 
['110.0', '116.5', '123.5', '130.8', '138.6', '146.8', '155.6', '164.8', '174.6', '185.0', '196.0', '207.6', '220.0', '233.1', '246.9', '261.6', '277.2', '293.6', '311.1', '329.6', '349.2', '370.0', '392.0', '415.3'] 
['146.8', '155.6', '164.8', '174.6', '185.0', '196.0', '207.6', '220.0', '233.1', '246.9', '261.6', '277.2', '293.6', '311.1', '329.6', '349.2', '370.0', '392.0', '415.3', '440.0', '466.1', '493.8', '523.2', '554.3'] 
['196.0', '207.6', '220.0', '233.1', '246.9', '261.6', '277.2', '293.6', '311.1', '329.6', '349.2', '370.0', '392.0', '415.3', '440.0', '466.1', '493.8', '523.2', '554.3', '587.3', '622.2', '659.2', '698.4', '739.9'] 
['246.9', '261.6', '277.2', '293.6', '311.1', '329.6', '349.2', '370.0', '392.0', '415.3', '440.0', '466.1', '493.8', '523.2', '554.3', '587.3', '622.2', '659.2', '698.4', '739.9', '783.9', '830.5', '879.9', '932.2'] 
['329.6', '349.2', '370.0', '392.0', '415.3', '440.0', '466.1', '493.8', '523.2', '554.3', '587.3', '622.2', '659.2', '698.4', '739.9', '783.9', '830.5', '879.9', '932.2', '987.7', '1046.4', '1108.6', '1174.6', '1244.4']
```

Comment: You're a genius! I tried 103.8 * 2^(1/12) to get 110, so this clearly illustrates the pattern, and would be able to raise the power (1/12) to the note that I am wishing to get to, i.e. from 0 -> note 100 frequency would be a power of 10 (in my head). Thanks so much, Mr Snrub. - if you could edit up the question for some code that would be amazing to help out others.

Comment: Haha well I actually learned this from some guy my freshman year of college, and **I** was the one who was the guitar player. Sure, since you asked so kindly I'll add some code.

Comment: I have absolutely given up on attempting to put formatted math in my posts, though :-/